# mongodb saving in array not object

Tags: mongodb

```
location{0:[coordinates:{0,0}],type:"Point"}
```

Some reason location is being saved in an array and not an object.

```
  traffic.findOneAndUpdate(
                 {'traffic_id':json.features[i].attributes.Id, 'object_id':json.features[i].attributes.OBJECTID},
                    {'location': [{coordinates:[long,lat],type:"Point"}],'Report':json.features[i].attributes.Location,'TrafficImpact':json.features[i].attributes.TrafficImpact, 'IncidentType':json.features[i].attributes.IncidentType},
                    {
                        upsert: true,new: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true
                    }, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('ERROR when submitting traffic');
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });
```

And my scheme is

```
  const TrafficScheme = new mongoose.Schema({
    object_id:{
        type:Number,
    },
    traffic_id:{
        type:Number,
    },
    Report:{
        type:String,
    },
    TrafficImpact:{
        type:String,
    },
    IncidentType:{
        type:String,
    },
    Road:{
        type:String,
    },
    EntryDate:{
        type:Date,
    },
    UpdateDateTime:{
        type:Date,
    },
    typeOfData:{
        type:String,
        default:"traffic",
    },
    cleared:{
        type:String,
        default:"false",
    },
    location: {
        type: Object,
       // index: { unique: true }
    },
    

  }, { collection: 'datafeed_beta'});
  



module.exports = mongoose.model('traffic', TrafficScheme);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `location` field is an array since you're passing it as an array to the `findOneAndUpdate` function (note the square brackets surrounding the value).  The function persists the value passed to it, which in this case contains an array for the `location` field.

```js
traffic.findOneAndUpdate(
  ...,
  {'location': [{coordinates:[long,lat],type:"Point"}], ...},
  ...
});
```

If you wish for it to not be an array, make sure the value you're passing to `findOneAndUpdate` is an object, not an array:

```js
traffic.findOneAndUpdate(
  ...,
  {'location': {coordinates:[long,lat],type:"Point"}, ...},
  ...
});
```